# sort and limit castor query

Tags: java, castor, oql

I am attempting to return a single object via castor query that has the earliest date.

This is the sort of thing I have been trying:
**SELECT p FROM model.objects.Product p LIMIT $1 WHERE p.status=$2 ORDER BY p.statusDate;**

This results in: **org.exolab.castor.jdo.oql.OQLSyntaxException: An incorrect token type was found near WHERE (found KEYWORD_WHERE, but expected END_OF_QUERY**

I am using version 0.9.6 which I believe supports this kind of thing.

Any hints or pointers much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with either SQL or OQL, but doesn't the limit clause need to appear last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, it indeed appears that the LIMIT clause must appear after the ORDER BY clause. See the [Castor query syntax](http://www.castor.org/1.2/oql.html#Syntax).

Comment: Thanks, it works :).I had tried this but query failed from me leaving ; at the end of the query. I finally picked up on this.